# Is the temp directory deleted when the app binary is updated by appstore?

Tags: iphone

Please help me with a solution.My app uses some video files which are saved in temp directory.Is these files will be deleted or refreshed when we update the version of already installed app from appstore.How could i handle the data storage when the app updation occurs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that currently (iOS5) your directory structure remains untouched during an update.

Going forward... who knows? In general, *user data* is protected between updates. So Apple won't delete settings or keychain data or anything in your Documents directory. I would say that almost anything else is fair game to be removed when your app is not running. They specifically mention the Caches directory (on low disk space rather than updating an app), but a temp directory might also be a reasonable candidate.

Comment: Do u mean that the data (video files) in temp directory wont be available once the app is updated.

Comment: Read the first paragraph in my answer.